# How Emacs determines a unit of work to undo

Tags: emacs

When you enter the command <kbd>C-/</kbd>, Emacs undoes some part of your recent changes to a buffer. When you enter <kbd>C-/</kbd> again, it undoes another chunk of work.

I have read the [Emacs manual entry on Undo](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Undo.html#Undo) but it is vague about exactly how it works. The manual says "Consecutive character insertion commands are usually grouped together into a single undo record" but it does not explain how it decides the number of character insertion commands that constitute a group. The number of characters it puts in a group seems random.

Can anyone explain the algorithm Emacs uses to group characters into undo records?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The logic for setting undo boundaries is mostly in `self-insert-command` which is implemented in [`cmds.c`](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/src/cmds.c). You'll have to read the code for the full story, but basically:

- As long as you are just typing characters, there's an undo boundary every 20 characters you type.
- But if you issue a different editing command (you kill a word, for example), this causes an undo boundary to be added immediately, resetting the character count.
- Certain "hairy" insertions (as determined by `internal_self_insert`) cause an an undo boundary to be added immediately, and the character count to be reset. Reading the code, it looks as though these are: (1) in `overwrite-mode`, if you overwrote a character with one that has a different width, e.g. typing over a tab; (2) if the character you inserted caused an abbreviation to be expanded; (3) if the character you typed caused `auto-fill-mode` to insert indentation.
- In addition, any editing command that decides it would be a good idea to have an undo boundary can request it by calling `undo-boundary`. This does not cause the character count to be reset.