# How to change granularity level of undo in emacs evil-mode with undo-tree?

Tags: vim, emacs, emacs24, evil-mode

These are some awesome options: emacs-24, evil-mode (using vim bindings in emacs), and undo-tree.

However, when I'm in edit mode (insert mode), I sometimes jump around for a number inserts, deletes, etc. before hitting escape and leaving insert mode.

"Undo" takes the whole insert (including deletes) as one edit. For example, I can't undo the paragraph I accidentally deleted without undo'ing the whole delete!

Is there any way to fix this?

Here are some related links:

- [How Emacs determines a unit of work to undo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590889/how-emacs-determines-a-unit-of-work-to-undo)
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_undo_branches
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modified_undo_behavior
- [This tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Recover_from_accidental_Ctrl-U) probably has best explanation from the vim side.

Here are the vim mappings that convert certain vim commands so that they can be undone:

```
inoremap <c-u> <c-g>u<c-u>
inoremap <c-w> <c-g>u<c-w>
inoremap <End> <C-g>u<End>
inoremap <BS> <c-g>u<BS>
inoremap <CR> <c-g>u<CR>
inoremap <del> <c-g>u<del>
```

What is needed is for the undo mode inside of emacs evil undo-tree to track additional events besides just leaving insert mode. For example, you should be able to stay in insert mode a long time and then undo any sort of delete, cut, paste.

Comment: Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590889/how-emacs-determines-a-unit-of-work-to-undo, the extra commands within evil need to call undo-boundary.

Comment: Only because it hasn't been said yet: "You should treat insert mode like you're running over a hot bed of coals; get out of there as soon as possible".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try [evil-want-fine-undo](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/blob/master/evil-vars.el#L331):

> Whether actions are undone in several steps.
> There are two possible choices: nil ("no") means that all
> changes made during insert state, including a possible delete
> after a change operation, are collected in a single undo step.
> Non-nil ("yes") means that undo steps are determined according
> to Emacs heuristics, and no attempt is made to aggregate changes.

```
(setq evil-want-fine-undo t)
```

Comment: This might actually be the answer! I'll let you know in a day or so.

Comment: Wonderful, still saved my day! But the link is broken :/

Answer (score 1):

Is this specific to undo tree? I don't use it, so the following might not apply...

I'm not sure if you can modify the amount of editing that the undo mechanism considers to be a single unit, but what you can do is:

Select a region first and then type the undo key, and Emacs will only undo changes that were made in that region.

That can be very useful.

Comment: This probably has more to do with evil simulating the vim behavior, which needs the modifications shown above.